# Laravel - Pass datas from DB to showRegistrationForm()

Tags: laravel

I started some weeks ago learning laravel and I have started to create my web app but i have a problem and I need your help.

I created an authentication system with make:auth command, added fields, and customed my forms.

Now, I'm working on a referral system. Each user has a unique affiliate_id and a ref link like : http://127.0.0.1:8000/?ref=WZv7Crm40Z.

When a visitor click on this link, the value WZv7Crm40Z is saved in cookies.
What I want is, when the registration form is loaded by the visitor, the value WZv7Crm40Z is compared with the DB and that the username linked to this value is displayed on the registration form.

I tried to work on the showRegistrationForm() but i think that i can't import datas from my DB on this function. I have always this error "Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\db' not found".

I saw some topics on that subjects but they create datas directly in the showRegistrationForm() so they are not imported from a DB.

Maybe it's not the best way to do that i want ? You have another idea ?
There is no problem about security to looking for datas in the DB on the registration form ? (when the visitor is not logged in).

Thank you for your help and sorry for my English... I'm french ! :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you just want to solve the error, just add `use DB;` above the `class` definition/below `namespace` definition. If you still can't solve the issue or if you want more assistance, please include minimal, complete, verifiable example in your question. Good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course query database

Try this

Add this method on **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php**

```php
 <?php
 use App\User;
 //Or if you want DB Facade
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

//....

public function showRegistrationForm(Request $request)
{
    $referer = User::where('referer', $request->ref)->first();

    return view('auth.register', compact('referer'));
}
```

Comment: Wouah I think that i had just forgotten "use App\User" .... I have just finished my referral system and email confirmation ! Thank's a lot ! :)

Comment: Okay, You had forgetten `use App\User` or `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`. Your welcome ! :)